# Recursive data structure separate each branch

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recursion

I have a recursive data structure like the example below, the goal I hope it can be each branch, from null (parentTagId) extend to as long as final one.

I have no idea how to do it, any suggestion will be appreciated!!

origin data:

```
[ 
  { TagId: 2, ParentTagId: null, Name: 'women' },
  { TagId: 5, ParentTagId: 2, Name: 'bottom' },
  { TagId: 4, ParentTagId: 2, Name: 'top' },
  { TagId: 7, ParentTagId: 4, Name: 'shirt' },
  { TagId: 8, ParentTagId: 4, Name: 'tshirt' },
  { TagId: 12, ParentTagId: 7, Name: 'longsleeve' },
  { TagId: 16, ParentTagId: null, Name: 'men' }
]
```

Expected result:

```
women > bottom  
women > top > shirt > longsleeve   
women > tshirt  
men
```

output data:

```
[
  {
    path: [ 
      { TagId: 2, ParentTagId: null, Name: 'women' },
      { TagId: 5, ParentTagId: 2, Name: 'bottom' }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: [
      { TagId: 2, ParentTagId: null, Name: 'women' },
      { TagId: 4, ParentTagId: 2, Name: 'top' },
      { TagId: 7, ParentTagId: 4, Name: 'shirt' },
      { TagId: 12, ParentTagId: 7, Name: 'longsleeve' }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: [
      { TagId: 2, ParentTagId: null, Name: 'women' },
      { TagId: 4, ParentTagId: 2, Name: 'top' },
      { TagId: 8, ParentTagId: 4, Name: 'tshirt' }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: [
      { TagId: 16, ParentTagId: null, Name: 'men' }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to convert **origin data** into **output data**, or do you already have **output data** and you want to convert it to something else? Are you wanting to do the conversion via PHP or via javascript? Are you trying to put the json into a php array?

Comment: @Vidul homework? no its my job I get the data from server side, but I can't find any related example how to solve this...

Comment: @Jakar I only got origin data , try to find how to convert to output data.   I hope solve this via javascript.

Comment: Why there is a `men` node but no `women` node in the expected result?

Comment: @zerkms because there are two base nulls for ParentTagId men and women. and then the children nodes are linked by the TagId... but there are no child nodes for men so its by itself

Comment: What I dont understand is your output data set is invalid syntax. if you have an object you need to have a key to go with the value. would you update it please? I don't have time to answer this right now, but if no one does I can get to it in a few hours :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell Thanks! I update now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider your input data as a tree. You want to generate the `path` to each **leaf**. A leaf is a tag with a `TagId` that is not referenced as `ParentTagId` by any other tag.

So the easiest solution would be:

1. Iterate over all tags and build a set (i.e. a list with unique entries) of all `ParentTagId` values. For your data, that is `[2,4,7]`.
2. Find your leaves by iterating over all tags and picking those where the `TagId` is not in that set. For your data, that is `[5,8,12,16]`.
3. Write a function `getTagById` to retrieve a tag by its id.
4. Write a recursive function to generate the path.
5. Iterate over all leaves and push the result of `getPath([], leaf)` into an array `paths`. After that, `paths` contains the path to each leaf as array of tags.
6. Build your output based on `paths`.

Code for step 1:

```
var parentTagIdSet = [];
for (var i = 0; i < originData.length; ++i) {
  var parentTagId = originData[i].ParentTagId;
  if (parentTagId != null && parentTagIdSet.indexOf(parentTagId) == -1) {
    parentTagIdSet.push(parentTagId);
  }
}
```

Code for step 2:

```
var leaves = [];
for (var i = 0; i < originData.length; ++i) {
  var tag = originData[i];
  if (parentTagIdSet.indexOf(tag.TagId) == -1) {
    leaves.push(tag);
  }
}
```

Code for step 3:

```
function getTagById(id) {
  for (var i = 0; i < originData.length; ++i) {
    var tag = originData[i];
    if (tag.TagId == id) {
      return tag;
    }
  }
  // If you finish the loop without returning, a ParentTagId is wrong.
  return null;
}
```

Code for step 4:

```
function getPath(path, currentTag) {
   if (currentTag == null) {
     // If you end up in here, some ParentTagId was wrong.
     path.reverse();
     return path;
   }
   path.push(currentTag);
   var parentId = currentTag.ParentTagId;
   if (parentId == null) {
     path.reverse();
     return path;
   } else {
     return getPath(path, getTagById(parentId));
   }
 }
```

Code for step 5:

```
var paths = [];
for (var i = 0; i < leaves.length; ++i) {
  paths.push(getPath([], leaves[i]));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I don't understand step1 you mean set like `[null,1,2...]` all parentTagId ?

Comment: Yes. "Set" is a term to describe a list that has no duplicate entries. For your example data, the set should be `[2, 4, 7]`.

Comment: I update function in your answer I don't understand what is step2 doing?

Comment: I have edited my answer to contain the sample code for each step (except for the last one, I think you know how to get there).

Comment: Thanks for description!!

Answer (score 0):

You basically want an object with structure like the following...

```
class Trie implements IteratorAggregate
{
    protected $parent;
    protected $children = [];

    public function insert(Node $node)
    {
        $node->parent     = $this;
        $this->children[] = $node;
    }

    public function findById($id)
    {
        foreach($this->children as $childNode) {
            if ($childNode->TagId === $id) {
                return $childNode;
            }
            if ($childNode->hasChildren()) {
                $n = $childNode->findById($id);
                if ($n) {
                   return $n;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function hasChildren()
    {
        return (bool) count($this->children);
    }

    public function getIterator()
    {
        return new ArrayIterator($this->children);
    }
}
```

and the node...

```
class Node extends Trie
{
    public function __construct(stdClass $obj)
    {
        foreach($obj as $p => $v) {
            $this->$p = $v;
        }
    }
}
```

You can iterate over your list of objects and instantiate each node then insert those objects whose parent id is null into the root of the tree and for nodes with children insert directly to their nodes.

e.g.

```
$list = json_decode(<<<'JSON'
[ 
  { "TagId": 2, "ParentTagId": null, "Name": "women" },
  { "TagId": 5, "ParentTagId": 2, "Name": "bottom" },
  { "TagId": 4, "ParentTagId": 2, "Name": "top" },
  { "TagId": 7, "ParentTagId": 4, "Name": "shirt" },
  { "TagId": 8, "ParentTagId": 4, "Name": "tshirt" },
  { "TagId": 12, "ParentTagId": 7, "Name": "longsleeve" },
  { "TagId": 16, "ParentTagId": null, "Name": "men" }
]
JSON
);

$trie = new Trie;
/* Insert all of the parentless nodes */
foreach($list as $n => $obj) {
    if (!$obj->ParentTagId) {
        $trie->insert(new Node($obj));
        unset($list[$n]);
    }
}

/* Insert all of the child nodes */
foreach($list as $n => $obj) {
    $p = $trie->findById($obj->ParentTagId);
    if ($p) {
        $p->insert(new Node($obj));
        unset($list[$n]);
    }
}
```

Now when you iterator over `$trie` you have all the parent nodes and subsequently you can iterator over any of their children to dig deeper into the hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I hope can solve via javascript, thanks for your description! I will try use javascript do this test now

Comment: Sorry, this question was tagged [tag:php], so I thought you were looking for a PHP solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not very efficiant, not very pretty, but JavaScript

```js
    
    var input = [ 
      { TagId: 2, ParentTagId: null, Name: 'women' },
      { TagId: 5, ParentTagId: 2, Name: 'bottom' },
      { TagId: 4, ParentTagId: 2, Name: 'top' },
      { TagId: 7, ParentTagId: 4, Name: 'shirt' },
      { TagId: 8, ParentTagId: 4, Name: 'tshirt' },
      { TagId: 12, ParentTagId: 7, Name: 'longsleeve' },
      { TagId: 16, ParentTagId: null, Name: 'men' }
    ]
    
    var output = []
    var path = []
    function drill(el){
      path.push(el)
      var val = input.filter(function(e){return e.ParentTagId === el.TagId})
      if(val.length > 0)
        val.forEach(drill)
      else {
          var e = path[0]
          while(e = findParent(e))
            path.unshift(e)
          output.push({
            path: path
          })
          path = []
          return
      }
    }
    function findParent(el){
    return input.filter(function(e){return e.TagId === el.ParentTagId})[0]
    }
    input.filter(function(e){return e.ParentTagId === null}).forEach(drill)
    console.log(output)
```